# Comparing two double variables Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, floating-point, double

```
double a = 10.123420834;
double b = 100.123412321;

if (a > b) {
// do something here
}
```

I am trying to compare the two values, the code above doesn't seems to work. Any idea?

Comment: What doesn't work?  Is the "do something here" part executing, even though your example has a < b?

Comment: `a` is not greater than `b`, so `// do something here` will never be executed.

Comment: While we're at it: for true correctness, try to avoid comparing two floating-point variables to each other; rather, try to compare the difference between them to a small 'epsilon' - the smallest amount of acceptable discrepancy between them while they would still be considered equal. `float`s and `double`s have some nuances that make them behave funny in comparisons; it doesn't always work as you'd expect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code is correct.

Note that your snippet is equivalent to

```
float a = 10.123420834;
float b = 100.123412321;

if (a > b) {
// do something here
}
```

since Objective C uses `double` by default unless the number is followed by an `f`.

Also note that `a < b`, so the `if` statement will always evaluate to `FALSE`. Hence you may want to do

```
double a = 10.123420834;
double b = 100.123412321;

if (a > b) {
// do something here
} else {
// do something else here
}
```

to test this properly.

Answer (score 1):

```
double a = 10.123420834
double b = 100.123412321
```

You need to have a semicolon at the end of each of those lines.

Answer (score 0):

The code in your example is correct. Your problem must be in the "do something here", or elsewhere.